# Posting on same form in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, post

I want to search for a product...so I have made a form...

but my products are being retreived in the doGet() method
and when I search for a product, the doPost() method is called....

SO what should i Do?

Comment: you're not describing what your problem is. why is it a problem that some requests are GETs and others POSTs?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually unclear what your problem is. If you want the form submit to be idempotent/bookmarkable, then just remove `method="post"` from the HTML `<form>` element if you want the request to be bookmarkable. Don't forget to remove `doPost()` method from the servlet as well.

Or if you actually want to let the form submit to a different servlet, then just create another servlet, register/map it the same way but on a bit different URL pattern and finally change the `action` URL of the HTML `<form>` element.

Comment: can i use multiple servlets on the same jsp page?

Comment: the problem is that i am using one servlet for my jsp page... and i have 2 forms on my jsp page also

thats why i asked the question above..

Comment: Truly you can use multiple servlets. I don't see why that wouldn't work. Just let the form action URL point to a different servlet. Did you try it?

Comment: Well I didnt think you could have multiple servlets for the same jsp apge..silly me...this problem wouldnt have happened if i tried that out before..